# Xquery error in WebHarvest

Tags: java, screen-scraping, xquery, webharvest

I'm using [WebHarvest](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/) to parse some html. I get the following error in WebHarvest's ide on the function that follows, and I don't understand what's wrong. I'm trying to create a function that trims a string.

**Error**:

> Error executing XQuery expression
>   (Xquery=[declare variable $xqsource
>   external; let $result :=
>   normalize-space($xqsource) return 
>   $result])!

Edit2: The log reports the following SAX Error:

> [...] **Caused by:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content
>   is not allowed in prolog**

I don't understand what this means in this case.

**Function**'s parameters: sourceString, the string to trim

```
<function name="trim">
    <return>
        <xquery>
            <xq-param name="xqsource">
                <var name="sourceString" />
            </xq-param>
            <xq-expression><![CDATA[
                declare variable $xqsource external;

                let $result := normalize-space($xqsource)
                    return 
                     $result
                ]]>
            </xq-expression>
        </xquery>
    </return>
</function>
```

Edit: sourceString is a string composed of alphanumeric chars, new lines and spaces, like

> "   blabla - bla2
>
> "

Comment: I can reproduce the error testing the XQuery expression with Saxon. What's the `sourceString` value?

Comment: @Alejandro: do you think the xquery code is correct? Anyway, the strings passed are string with new lines, alphanumeric chars and spaces inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default type of xq-param is `node()` (cf [manual](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/manual.php#xquery)). Therefore, WebHarvest tries to parse your variable content as XML (SAXParseException is an XML parsing error, not a particular XQuery error).

You should add a `string` type declaration to your param:

```
<xq-param name="xqsource" type="string">
  <var name="sourceString" />
</xq-param>
```

Does that help?

Comment: Argh!! I missed that parameter type because the example used an xml var which is the default!!! Thank you VERY MUCH, now it works!